# How to change the color of Table of Contents from red to black?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color

Now the color of Table of Contents is red, i want it be black color. 
I use hyperref

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
```

if I change it to

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

or

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
```

Then, the red color is changed to black, but with a red color rectangle. 
How to make it as black color? just like as a normal book does

Comment: try `hidelinks=true`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default colour for (internal) links are red, provided by the key `linkcolor`. To keep links active but with a `black` colour, use

```
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor  = black
}
```

For more on link colours, see section **3.5 Extension options** of the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) [HTML documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-90003.5).