# Set color to hyperlink except in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, report

When I set `\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}` to make the references of figures/tables blue, the TOC was also changed to blue. How can I change the link color to blue except change the default color (black) of the TOC?

Comment: Have you tried placing the `hypersetup` statement *after* the table of contents?

Comment: @ Johannes_B: Great! Very simple way to do that, now it works well, thank you!

Comment: alternatively: `{ \hypersetup{hidelinks} \tableofcontents }`

Comment: It's not necessarily better, just different :)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306617/43317

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to achieve this, one way which

- preserves the capability to click the links
- allows coloured links before the table of contents

is to use `{ \hypersetup{hidelinks} \tableofcontents }`. Pay attention to the curly brackets around the code, this puts the `\hypersetup` together with the table of contents inside a group, so it will not effect the remaining document.