# Switch font and color of TOC and LOT titles

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, color, styles

What I'm trying to do is pretty basic it seems, but it's also above my pay grade: change the font and the color used for the TOC title `Contents` and the LOT title `List of Tables` (see attached screen caps).

I'd like the Candara font I use for my chapters, and the color I've picked for them, to be used for both "Table of Contents" and "List of Tables"

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
%\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
%\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}

%\usepackage{lscape} %to put the long table of dwellings sideways
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec,color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% To make TOC in two columns and List of Tables into one column.
\usepackage{multitoc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{toc}}{%
            \ifnum\multicolumntoc>1
            \begin{multicols}{\multicolumntoc}%
                \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
            \end{multicols}%
            \else
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
            \fi}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lot}}{%
            \ifnum\multicolumnlot>1
            \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlot}%
                \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
            \end{multicols}%
            \else
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
            \fi}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lof}}{%
            \ifnum\multicolumnlof>1
            \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlof}%
                \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
            \end{multicols}%
            \else
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
            \fi}{}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\multicolumnlot}{1}


% CHAPTER, SECTION, SUBSECTION STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Candara}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\color{blue}\filcenter\fontsize{35}{35}\headingfont} % Size of Chapter1&Chapter
{\huge\MakeUppercase\headingfont{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{12pt}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
        (0pt,-117pt)$) {\includegraphics[width=14cm]{chapterHead_10cm}};}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50mm}{42.5mm}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\color{orange}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\color{orange}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\color{orange}\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}

\begin{document}

% To inlcude background wallpaper/image
%\CenterWallPaper{1}{TKML_ESB_Page_Background_2}

%\layout    

% FRONTMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\clearpage

\onecolumn
\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Preface}
\blindtext
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\twocolumn

\clearpage

% MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mainmatter

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Contents]
[image: LOF]

Comment: Something like `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textcolor{green}{Contents}}}` I can't test, because no MWE.

Comment: Thank you. I added a clause to switch "Contents" to the heading font I'm using and it does work ... but it also generates errors. This part \addto\captionsenglish is highlighted in red.

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: Sorry. I was away. The text is now compilable.

Comment: You should not try to use legacy 8-bit fonts together with `fontspec`, which selects modern fonts. It won’t work (although it could be made to if you really wanted). You should remove the packages `fontenc`, `textcomp`, `intputenc` and `newpxtext`, and add the command `\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Candara}`. If you want a font that looks like `newpx`, either replace `Candara` with`TeX Gyre Pagella`, or better yet, use the original both of them are cloned from: `\setmainfont[Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common, Rare, TeX}]{Palatino Linotype}`.

Comment: I did try to implement your suggestion `\setmainfont[Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common, Rare, TeX}]{Palatino Linotype}` and thought it worked until I realized that one of the accents I have to use quite extensively in the text < ǘ > appeared as < ü' >. So I went back to using `newpxtext`. I think I'm going to have to post a question on the proper use of fonts in a text filled with loads of esoteric accents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are loading a lot of packages I guess you do not need. In the following MWE I reduced the loaded packages to be more minimal. If packages are commented please read the comment explaining why I did that.
2. Because you are loading package `fontspec` I added command `\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Candara}` to use font Chandara for the document.
3. Because you are already using package `tocloft` you can  use the following lines to manipulate the used code and color in TOC and LOF:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft
   \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\Huge\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft
   \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft
   \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft
   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft
   \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft
   ```
4. I use command `\Blinddocument` from package `blindtext` to generate dummy text for a complete document ...

With the following complete MWE (see important code changings marked with `<======`):

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}

\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT <===================
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
%\usepackage{pdfcolmk} % <==== not needed with xelatex
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Candara} % <====================================

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% To make TOC in two columns and List of Tables into one column.
\usepackage{multitoc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{toc}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumntoc>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumntoc}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lot}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumnlot>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlot}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lof}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumnlof>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlof}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\multicolumnlot}{1}


% CHAPTER, SECTION, SUBSECTION STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Candara}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\color{blue}\filcenter\fontsize{35}{35}\headingfont} % Size of Chapter1&Chapter
{\huge\MakeUppercase\headingfont{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{12pt}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-117pt)$) {\includegraphics[width=14cm]{chapterHead_10cm}};}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50mm}{42.5mm}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\color{orange}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\color{orange}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\color{orange}\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft <=====
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\Huge\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft <=====
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft <==============
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft <===============
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft <============
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\color{green}\headingfont} % tocloft <==========


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\Blinddocument % <======================================================
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: toc]

As you can see the font and the color of the heading of TOC is changed, also the color of chapters, sections and subsections in TOC. `\cftchappagefont` changed the the page number for the chapters in the TOC, you can use `\cftsecpagefont` simular for sections etc.

Comment: Thank you. This did it. I then had a conflict between my hyperlinks color and the  color of the links in the TOC: both were the same when I wanted the two to be different. This simple trick fixed it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306613/how-to-change-the-color-of-only-table-of-contents-from-red-to-black

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Renew the commands `\cfttoctitlefont`, `\cftfigfont`, and `\cftlottitlefont` to any font style you want.

I removed the unnecessary codes for better readability.

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[]{tocbibind} % use this package to automatically insert list of tables and list of figures into the TOC

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Candara}
\newcommand{\toctitlefont}{\Huge \color{orange} \headingfont \bfseries} % font of the titles of lists (e.g., List of Tables)

% Change font style for TOC, LOT, and LOF here
    \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\toctitlefont}
    \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\tocsecpagefont} 
    \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\toctitlefont}




\begin{document}

% To inlcude background wallpaper/image
%\CenterWallPaper{1}{TKML_ESB_Page_Background_2}

%\layout    

% FRONTMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename} use tocbibind package and remove this
\listoftables
\clearpage

\listoffigures
\clearpage


\onecolumn
\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Preface}
\blindtext
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\twocolumn

\clearpage

% MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mainmatter

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

**Off-topic:** use `tocbibind` package for better handling of List of Tables, List of Figures, and Index. By default, it will automatically insert their location into the TOC. It also provides easy options like `nottoc`, `notlot`, `notlof` to determine whether tables of contents, list of tables, and list of figures will be inserted into the TOC

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the <tocbibind> package.