# Change the page numbers in the Table of Contents to red

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

Good morning,  I have just seen a [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196519/how-to-change-the-color-of-table-of-contents-from-red-to-black) titled by ''How to change the color of Table of Contents from red to black?'' and I'm really satisfied by the proposed answer as I want, knowing that the table of contents and the page numbers are both hyperlinked.

The proposed answer is:

```
{ \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
  \tableofcontents
}
```

**In addition to that**, I would like to keep the black color in the table of contents but I want:

- **Either** to change the color of the page numbers in this table to red
- **Or** frame these page numbers in a color square.

Comment: Not sure, if this is what you want to achieve, but `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}` removes the hyperlinks from the titles in the table of contents, hyperlinks the corresponding page numbers instead and prints these numbers in red. By removing the option `colorlinks=true`, the page numbers are surrounded by a red frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> I would like to ... change the color of the page numbers [in the ToC] [to red]

I suggest you load the `hyperref` package with the option `linktocpage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents

\bigskip
\hrule
\section{A A A} \clearpage
\section{B A B} \clearpage
\section{C C C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Do you have an idea how to frame the page numbers by a colored square.? Thank you again.

Comment: @AH - Just remove the option `colorlinks`. If necessary, specify the option `linkcolor=red` when loading `hyperref`.