# How to make red page numbers in table of contents while 'linktoc=all' and '\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}' are present?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color, tocloft

How can I make page numbers red in table of contents? I have

- `colorlinks=true`, `linkcolor=blue`, so standard internal links are blue;
- `linctoc=all`, so both table of contents entry names and page numbers are links (the dots themselves are not);
- `\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}` in the group generating the table of contents, so the links in the table of contents are black instead of blue everywhere else.

Finally, I hoped to change the color of the page numbers (to red, for example) in table of contents independently from the entry name color (black in this instace). As a start, I added `\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\color{red}}` to change the page numbers of sections, but it is ignored.

*(It is also ignored when placed inside the group generating the table of contents. Furthermore, it is ignored even if `\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}` is removed from the group.
Conversely, `\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}` has the intended effect...)*

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false, linktoc=all]{hyperref} % blue internal links for document; in TOC, entry name and page nr are links

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\color{red}} % does not work

\begin{document}
    {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black} % black links for table of contents (but you may comment this out, red color still not added)
    \tableofcontents} 
    
    \chapter{Example chapter}
    
    \section{Example section}
    
    \subsection{Example subsection}
    
This is some text.
\end{document}
```

---

The question [Change the page numbers in the Table of Contents to red](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405164/116907) by [A H](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/119987/a-h) is ***not** a duplicate*: there `linktoc=all` is replaced with `linktocpage`. This removes links from entry names which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide the link colour in the toc:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false, linktoc=all]{hyperref} % blue internal links for document; in TOC, entry name and page nr are links

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\color{red}} % does not work

\begin{document}
    {\hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \tableofcontents} 
    
    \chapter{Example chapter}
    
    \section{Example section}
    
    \subsection{Example subsection}
    
This is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you. However, I am having trouble extending it. Namely, the idea is to have it show red on screen, but always be black when printed (some type of `ocgx2` solution). Probably, I should ask a new question as it is, strictly speaking, beyond the scope here.

Comment: Follow-up question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694045/116907 is up.