# New color command \colorPlus[<color-when-printed>]{<color-in-PDF>} that behaves differently when viewed and printed

Tags: color, ocg, ocgx2

The aim is to **define a new command** `\colorPlus[<color-when-printed>]{<color-in-PDF>}` that

- works exactly like the usual `\color{<color-in-PDF-and-print>}` when used without optional argument as in `\colorPlus{<color-in-PDF}`;
- does some `osgx2`-type magic when an optional argument is given. For example, `\colorPlus[black]{red}` will make text show up red in the PDF but be black when printed.

According to some old comments from 2015 ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22609/how-can-i-have-text-colored-on-screen-and-black-on-printing#comment636496_22613), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22609/how-can-i-have-text-colored-on-screen-and-black-on-printing#comment636951_22613)) by [Mariano Suárez-Álvarez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/525/mariano-su%c3%a1rez-%c3%81lvarez) and Herbert/user2478, this should be possible. The question is then how to do it.

You may change the syntax of `\colorPlus`, or use some existing commands instead, if you believe to have a better syntax.

As a test, change `\color{red}` in the following MWE to `\colorPlus{black}{red}` to see if your solution is working.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false, linktoc=all]{hyperref} % blue internal links for document; in TOC, entry name and page nr are links
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

%%% Definition of \colorPlus{}  

%%%

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\color{red}} % change "\color{red}" to \colorPlus[black]{red} as a test

\begin{document}
    {\hypersetup{hidelinks}
    \tableofcontents} 
    
    \chapter{Example chapter}
    
    \section{Example section}
    
    \subsection{Example subsection}
    
This is some text.
\end{document}
```

The MWE is essentially from my earlier question *[How to make red page numbers in table of contents while 'linktoc=all' and '\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}' are present?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/693978/116907)* and [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693979/116907). The section page number is red when viewed in PDF (but, in this case, also when printed).

[image: Section page number is red in PDF]

Comment: I'm just throwing out a suggestion: but what about creating a sort of "overlay", like the hyperlink boxes?These boxes show up when viewing the PDF but not in print. Maybe one could shape the boxes so it overlaps exactley with the text? Btw: I don't know how to implement this idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`colorPlus` needs to be implemented as an environment, since filling the font outlines with optional colours depending on OC settings is done *after* the text has been inserted.

So, here is a solution based on internal code from `ocgx2`. Also, `tocloft` commands `\cftsecfillnum`, `\cftsecpagefont` and `\cftsecafterpnum` need to be redefined. Note that `pdfmanagement-testphase` must be enabled for the code to work.

The new environment is

```
\begin{colorPlus}[<printing colour>]{<viewing colour>}
...
\end{colorPlus}
```

Named colours and `xcolor` colour expressions can be used for `<printing color>` and `<viewing colour>`.

Works in Acrobat Reader and Chrome/Chromium PDF viewer plugin.

```latex
\DocumentMetadata{} % pdfmanagement-testphase needs to be enabled
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false, linktoc=all]{hyperref} % blue internal links for document; in TOC, entry name and page nr are links
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \begin{colorPlus}[<printing color>]{<viewing colour>}
% ...
% \end{colorPlus}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{colorPlus}{om}{
  \color_group_begin:
  \IfValueTF{#1}{ % optional printing colour given
    \ocgxii_colorlinks_init: % create OCGs for printing and viewing
    \color_select:n{#1}
    \color_export:nnN{#2}{backend}\l_tempb_tl
    \tl_set:Nx\l_tempa_tl{\tl_item:Nn\l_tempb_tl{1}} % model
    \tl_set:Nx\l_tempb_tl{\tl_item:Nn\l_tempb_tl{2}} % components
    \str_replace_all:Nnn\l_tempb_tl{~}{,}
    \tl_set:Nx\g_ocgxii_lnkcol_tl{{\l_tempa_tl}{\l_tempb_tl}}
    \ocgxii_colourlink_begin:
  }{
    \color_select:n{#2}
  }
  \ignorespaces
}{
  \unskip
  \IfValueT{#1}{\ocgxii_colourlink_end:}
  \color_group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftsecfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftsecleader}\nobreak
  \cftsecpagefont\makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]{#1}\cftsecafterpnum\par
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\begin{colorPlus}[black]{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\end{colorPlus}}

\begin{document}
{\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\tableofcontents} 

\chapter{Example chapter}

\section{Example section}

\subsection{Example subsection}
    
This is text in default colour.
\begin{colorPlus}[black!50!green]{blue}
The displayed and printed colours of this text may be different.
\end{colorPlus}
Again, text in default colour.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! The options `colorlinks=true`, `linkcolor=blue` and `linktoc=all` should be given separately with `hypersetup` according to documentation of `PDF management testphase` and `hyperref-generic` documentation, I believe. Also, as a note to future readers, `bookmark` options should also be given separately (via package `bookmark` and its option `\bookmarksetup`, for instance). And some colors for links are changed, most notably the color for citing, so you would need to change `citecolor` as well if so desired.

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer but too long for a comment.

`ocgcolorlinks` works by surrounding text in the PDF with `OC` markers:

```
/OC/OCPrint BDC
% stuff that should be used when printed
/EMC
/OC/OCView BDC
% stuff that should be used when view
EMC
```

Sadly it looks as if the "stuff" can't be simply a color instruction. There must be something that is drawn (text or graphic). That makes it difficult to handle content that contains line breaks or page breaks.

`hyperref` avoids problems with breaks by putting the link into a box and then typesetting it twice with different OC-settings, so it can handle only short pieces of text. The ocgx2 package allows line breaks by using clipping: it puts in the OC-settings large colored rectangles which cover the whole page and then changes the rendering mode of the text to clipping, so basically the text is cut out of the background. To handle page breaks the package stores a lot of info and reinstates the status at the begin of the next shipout. While the ocgx2-trick is quite ingenious I wouldn't be confident that it works well if the document is meant for professional printing (but I never tried) and I don't know how it behaves for long pieces of texts.

Now in your example you only want to color a short piece of text, and so the ocgx2 method is not needed. The main problems here are at first that as you use the `ocgcolorlinks` and the `linktoc=all` you already have OC-markers and so you get nesting. And as second that to print the text twice with the `hyperref` method you need to capture the text in a box. So you can't do simply a \colorPlus{red} and hope that it affects following text.

Comment: Thank you for the extended comment! In my experience, the difference of black-in-print `ocgx2` stuff in print versus usual black text is small, but it may be slightly noticeable. Your explanation of box creation leads me to another question. Could such tricks be used to identify `underfull boxes` too and mark them similarly how `overfull boxes` are marked with black boxes? Is this worth a question, or am I on the wrong track?